# 3rd party RAM options for Mac towers?

Tags: mac, memory

I recently came back into possession of my old G5 tower, and considering upgrading the RAM to use it as a workhorse for video editing.  What's the most cost-effective choice, as far as compatible RAM sticks are concerned?  Also, would the RAM be compatible with one of the newer Mac Pro towers, or would that be a separate investment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a variety of memory, inside the G5 tower, you are best off using the [Crucial Memory Advisor](http://www.crucial.com/) as there are so many G5 tower variations.

It will most likely not be compatible with a new Mac Pro tower as they are now on DDR3, The latest G5 tower took Dual-Channel DDR2 PC4200.